# How would an evil Oath of Devotion Paladin work?

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

So I can see Oath of Vengeance (to a degree) working with an evil paladin, I can also see Conquest, Trickery and obviously Oathbroken, but since 5e doesn't restrict alignments on classes, I'm curious on how anyone would play an evil Devotion paladin.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "right" answer to this question. How someone would play this is entirely opinion-based.

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. I am afraid this question is incompatible with our format, as explained by NautArch. Do stay around for other rpg-related questions though! Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 2):

### This basically comes down to subversion, perspective, and a clever (or contrived) reading of the oath's tenets.

The tenets of the Oath of Devotion Paladin, as written, clearly push a character toward doing good.  In order to twist them to evil, a character would need to believe they were fulfilling the tenets while still pursuing evil goals.  The character's worldview would need to be so twisted that they truly believe that the evil they are doing is actually not evil, and is bringing good to the world.

Let's look at the tenets of the oath, and see how one might twist them to evil.

> **Honesty**: Don’t lie or cheat. Let your word be your promise.

Maybe your character sees this as a challenge.  How far can they bend the truth without ever actually telling a lie?  They fill their conversations with leading statements that are in fact true, but often lead listeners to make wrong assumptions.  The character sees nothing wrong with this - they have done their duty in telling the truth, and it's not their fault if someone else jumped to a foolish, possibly dangerous, wrong conclusion.

> **Courage**: Never fear to act, though caution is wise.

This one is fairly easy.  "Never fear to act", sure, but in what way?  Maybe the evil Devotion Paladin uses this tenet of their oath as an excuse to throw their party into danger, knowing that if they lead a charge, the rest will follow.  Maybe this will lead to deaths in the party, or provoking a response from a powerful monster or organization against innocent civilians.

> **Compassion**: Aid others, protect the weak, and punish those who
>   threaten them. Show mercy to your foes, but temper it with Wisdom.

This one can be a little tricky to subvert, but let's try thinking in terms of scale.  By common sense, we think of exemplifying this tenet (specifically "protect the weak, and punish those who threaten them") by fighting off tyrants or monsters oppressing the common folk.  But an evil Devotion Paladin completely lacks this common sense.  They see a child pull the legs off a spider, and promptly cut the leg off of the child as a fair and just punishment.  They see an innkeeper laying out traps for mice ("the weak"), and decide a fair punishment would be to poison the innkeeper - and all of his guests.

> **Honor**: Treat others with fairness, and let your honorable deeds be an example to them. Do as much good as possible while causing the least amount of harm.

This is difficult to subvert, because the text specifically states "Do as much good as possible".  But Good and Evil are abstract concepts subject to human interpretation.  In D&D, Evil and Good are generally given objective definitions, but in reality it is rarely so clear-cut.  Good and Evil are often matters of perspective.  The Evil Oath of Devotion Paladin exemplifies this to the core.  Maybe "Good" to them means aesthetically pleasing.  They kill people they believe are ugly because they believe it is a service to the world.  Maybe "Good" to this character means naturally occurring.  They view Warforged (and/or any other race of construct-like beings) as abominations and are on a crusade to eliminate them.

> **Duty**: Be responsible for your Actions and their consequences, protect those entrusted to your care, and obey those who have just authority over you.

"Be responsible for your Actions and their consequences" - this is a somewhat ambiguous statement, anyway.  The Evil Devotion Paladin claims responsibility for their crimes by painting their name in letters of blood at the scene.  They accept the consequences by accepting challenges of duels to the death from all those involved, and winning.

"Protect those entrusted to your care" - Perhaps the Paladin waves this off by saying that none have ever been entrusted to their care.  On the other hand, they may see themselves as guardians of some arbitrary group thanks to an offhand comment by a civilian ("Oh, and watch out for the snakes in the garden").  Now, whenever that group seems threatened ("Time to weed the garden, and I'll set out some traps to keep the snakes away"), the Paladin responds with deadly force.

"Obey those who have just authority over you" - Again, maybe the Paladin doesn't believe that anyone has just authority over them. Maybe they're an anarchist.  Or, maybe they're a Tiefling, and believe that only fiends can have authority over them because of their fiendish blood.  Maybe a demon once saved their life, and they believe that gives the demon completely justified authority over them.

So here are a few ways a Paladin might follow the letter of the Oath of Devotion while subverting the spirit of the Oath to Evil.  Hopefully this is enough to spark the imagination.  But, as a disclaimer, remember to clear the idea with your DM before showing up to session 1 with an Evil Oath of Devotion Paladin.  It is well within DM rights to decide an Oath of Devotion Paladin does indeed have to be Good, and it may be that no amount of clever (or contrived) workarounds of the Oath's tenets will convince them otherwise.